# How to put an argument with single quote (it can be str or int)

Tags: php

I can't pass any string inside of my $r variable. It must be an integer so it can work..

```
echo '<tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="voirListe" value="O" onClick="javascript:listeFormulaire('.$r['username'].');">            
  [...]
      </tr>';
```

But if I do this

```
onClick="javascript:listeFormulaire(\'cbi'\);"
```

It will work.

But this one ain't working...Syntax error.

```
onClick="javascript:listeFormulaire(\'.$r['username'].\');"
```

So tell me guys, how can I pass a string argument?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code and in your code ur missing " at the end

```
onClick="javascript:listeFormulaire(\'.$r['username'].\');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
echo '<tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="voirListe" value="O" onClick="javascript:listeFormulaire('.$r[username].');">            
      </tr>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some space to see what's really going on...

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="voirListe" value="O" onClick="javascript:listeFormulaire(\'  '.$r['username'].'  \');">';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="voirListe" value="O" onClick="javascript:listeFormulaire('<?php echo $r['username']; ?>')"; />
```